# How to shrink/split large PDF to less than 50 MB

Tags: windows-8, pdf, osx-lion

I have a large tech PDF. It's 2500 pages with images and 100 MB in size. I'd like to try and read it on my Kindle. To my understanding, PDFs have to be less than 50 MB in order to read on the Kindle.

I downloaded PDFSAM, but if it splits the PDF into multiple PDFs by the number of pages, the file size doesn't seem to shrink more than 5 MB (so 95MB). I even tried breaking the PDF down every 100 pages.

It has a feature that will split by file size, but it doesn't seem to do anything to this PDF.

Is there a free way that I can get it down to less than 50 MB?  I don't know if I can lower the quality of the PDF to make it smaller (might not be drastic enough though), split it up into multiple ones less than 50 MB, or even strip the images out of it.

I tried Calibre, which converted the file to a MOBI format. However, the MOBI file was about 200MB, and Gmail wouldn't accept it as an email attachment.

Comment: afaik, a mobi file is a zip file. try renaming the mobi to "zip" and then extract it. you will be able to identify the reason for the large file sizes. Presumably the images are the problem.

Comment: Have you tried printing to a i.e. PDF Creator but just pages 1-100 and checking what the output file size is?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @l1zard Windows8 and/or OSX Lion

Comment: @horatio I changed the file extension to zip, but windows said the archive was empty, and 7 zip said that it wasn't an archive

Comment: I see a lot of google noise regarding MOBI and Zip, so it *was* possible (and may be unless encrypted or a newer version). In any event: if it didn't work, then it didn't work!

Comment: @Karan I just figured out how to have pdftk4all split the PDF, and each file is the same size as the original, even though they only contain a subset of the pages.  Not sure why though...

Comment: @Darius I tested it out and it does seem like a very time consuming, but viable solution. Why did you submit it as a comment?

Comment: @Hoppe I believe PDF Creator can be scripted so all you would have to do is to create a batch file to do that :)

Comment: @Karan So if you did divide the big.pdf into 5 files each file would be pretty small then?

Comment: @Karan pdftk4all is just a gui for pdftk. Anyway, I tried it from the command line as you suggested and got the same result - the file size is 90 MB. Feel free to try it on the PDF at http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/KenticoCMS_DevGuide.pdf. Seems like your solution works on some PDFs, but not this one unfortunately

Comment: You are right, there's something really weird about this file. I don't know if it's corrupted or what. I used pdftk's burst mode to split it into individual pages, and even though most pages contained text they each were around ~90MB! Just doesn't make sense. :/

Comment: Does anyone know how to use the itextsharp c# library to remove all images from a PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delete all images from a copy of the PDF, via a few lines of either: [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831194/how-can-i-remove-all-images-drawings-from-a-pdf-file-and-leave-text-only-in-java), [C#,  or VB.Net](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Delete+Images+from+the+PDF+File), alternatively you could use the PDF->Mobi conversion tool in [Calibre](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html), as this can reduce image quality to suit a kindle.

Comment: The Aspose library is $800 for a single license. Calibre didn't reduce the file size when it converted it to Mobi... It made it bigger.

Comment: What options did you set for the Calibre conversion e.g.  
`ebook-convert --no-images someFile.pdf someFile.mobi`
Also note: Aspose offers a 30 day trial, while the **pdfbox** libraries and Calibre App are FREE.

Answer (score 3):

PDF Scissors was developed to take the hassle out of PDF reading on Kindles. It may be beneficial to you.

http://www.pdfscissors.com/

Comment: I just tried PDF scissors. It was helpful to remove the margins, but for some reason the PDF actually got 5 MB bigger :(

Comment: @Hoppe Thx for the feedback, the only other good tool I know is http://sejda.com/

Comment: thank you for the suggestions.  Ironically the limit on Sedja.com is 50 MB as well

Comment: @Hoppe I hope something turns up, if I find out more I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can try the instructions of this page (Linux only) (french): [Optimiser un fichier PDF sous Linux](http://howto.biapy.com/fr/developpement/shell-unix/optimiser-un-fichier-pdf-sous-linux).

Install needed software:

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils ghostscript
```

Provice original PDF file path:

```
PDF_FILE="original.pdf"
```

Provide output PDF file path:

```
OPTIMIZED_PDF_FILE="optimized.pdf"
```

And run the optimization:

```
command pdftops \
        -paper match \
        -nocrop \
        -noshrink \
        -nocenter \
        -level3 \
        -q \
      "$PDF_FILE" - \
  | command ps2pdf14 \
        -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
        -dUseFlateCompression=true \
        -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK \
        -dConvertCMYKImagesToRGB=false \
        -dOptimize=true \
        -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
      - "$OPTIMIZED_PDF_FILE"
```

Alternatively, you can use this command line to reduce the image quality to 72dpi:

```
command pdftops \
        -paper match \
        -nocrop \
        -noshrink \
        -nocenter \
        -level3 \
        -q \
      "$PDF_FILE" - \
  | command ps2pdf14 \
        -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
        -dUseFlateCompression=true \
        -dOptimize=true \
        -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB \
        -dUseCIEColor=true \
        -r72 \
        -dDownsampleGrayImages=true \
        -dGrayImageResolution=72 \
        -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false \
        -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
        -dDownsampleMonoImages=true \
        -dMonoImageResolution=72 \
        -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
        -dDownsampleColorImages=true \
        -dColorImageResolution=72 \
        -dAutoFilterColorImages=false \
        -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
        -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
      - "$OPTIMIZED_PDF_FILE"
```

These commands are implemented online by [PdfCruncher](http://pdfcruncher.org/).